# Javascript checking for blanks in form

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm Dutch please be kind on the grammar.
I've looked online and i cannot seem to figure out how to check if a form was submitted when empty.

I will not be adding code since it keeps telling me its not formatted properly even though i do that automatically in VSC
I think the question is self explanatory but still. If u got a question ask it. I really need help A.S.A.P i got the talk tomorrow.

When i erase(wis)
it also erases the dropdown Heads or Tails(HorT)
Which means its blank.
When someone then plays then CANNOT win.
If they do not put in a bet they will win/lose NaN.

I have checks in for if they have put <=0 and if they have the actual balance.
I just cannot seem to figure this part out.

Any help would be amazing.
I've tried `if(HorT == ""), (HorT.length === 0)`
And a few others i didn't even understand what i was typing.
Im a beginner in coding and had some fun with this assignment last year but now i have to present it for an intership place.

It says i have to explain more but i dont know how to explain more.

Comment: @Without any code your question is not understandable. I have no clue where to start helping you. And what do you mean by "I just cannot seem to figure this part out"?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
if (HorT == "") {your code}
```

Should have worked. I think what you could have done wrong was not add the `else` part of the if statement. If you just did the if statement and skipped the else part, the code would continue running, but would also run the code within the `if` statement if the string was empty.

Basically, what this code does is check if the string (the letters) in the variable `HorT` is empty, and does the code inside the `{ }`. So, if I wrote

```
if (HorT == "") {
console.log('empty') // or whatever you would like to happen if the submitted form is empty
} else {
    // what do to if the submitted form is NOT empty
}
```

It would log in your console `empty` when the variable is empty, and if it was not (thus, the `else` part of the statement), it would execute the rest of your code.

Good luck with your internship!

Edit: talked to him about debugging on discord. the parsed variable actually was 1 (found by logging the variable), so the else if statement should be `else if (HorT == 1)`. We also talked about handling different errors such as when HorT is NaN, in which we discussed having `else if (HorT != HorT) {error handling}` as the handler.

Comment: For some reasons it won't put enters.

Comment: I understand ur point i should make my if's else if's and im dumb. My first lines of code are all checking if everything is filled incorrectly. Then i got else statements with if's inside of them running the actual game. i now have this: `if (bet <= 0) { 
output 
} 
else if(HorT == "") { 
output 
} 

else if (bet > TotalBalance) { var NeededMoney = bet - TotalBalance; output 
} 

else { if (xxxx) { 
} `
But it still just goes and runs the rest of the code. Thanks for trying to help and indeed what i did should work in my eyes also but its not. –

Comment: Is the rest of your code within the `else` statement?

Comment: Yes any chance u can dm me on discord: Hykonic#5822. Its alot easier to share code there.